# playframework: Request.current в Job

Tags: java, playframework

Я использую playframework, и мне необходимо распараллелить одну задачу. Есть модуль, методы которого используют `Request.current`, в частности FbGraph. Эти методы я использую в своих Job'ах. Проблема состоит в том, что когда выполняется Job, на него выделяется отдельный поток. В этом потоке `Request.current = null`. Следовательно, у меня нарушается работа FbGraph. Можно ли как-то передать значение текущего запроса в job? Или нужно кардинально переписывать модуль?

Comment: Это вероятно серьёзный косяк FbGraph. Хотя, честно говря, не совсем ясно, зачем его распараллеивать? И да, передавать реквест в джобу - большая кривизна. Надо искать способ обойтись без этого.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня получается довольно много запросов к Fb, и тут есть два решения. Либо написать какой то менеджер запросов, который бы все запросы скомпоновал в один или распараллелить эти самые запросы.

Answer (score 1):

В таком случае, почему бы вам просто не использовать обычные `Thread` и `Runnable`, а в job по расписанию запускать все потоки?